# User-defined function results do not appear in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote user-defined function called myaverage, which calculates weighted average of 3 numbers:

```
Function myaverage(x, y, z) As Double
    Dim a As Single
    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    Dim z As Double
    a = 0.4 * x + 0.5 * y + 0.1 * z
    myaverage = a
End Function
```

But if I type  `=myaverage(A1:A3)`, I cannot see the result.

Comment: I type in the excel sheet =myaverage(A1:A3) where in the specific cells are my random numbers and it is not appear the answer

Comment: Better declare `a` as double, like all the others. Also, make sure there is no overflow, otherwise you will have #NA as result.

Comment: I change it and write Dim a as Double, but it still appears #VALUE!

Comment: Make the function Public.

Comment: Good starter Q&A. So as you see, put as many neceessary details to your question (from beginning) as possible. (Of course, avoid unnecessary stuff.) Good questions are answered relatively fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had double declarations. I mean, `x` was alreaday declared in the signature and you re-declared it in the function body. So this will work:

```vb
Public Function myaverage(x As Double, y As Double, z As Double) As Double
    myaverage = 0.4 * x + 0.5 * y + 0.1 * z
End Function
```

- Do not forget the function must be placed in Module (e.g. Module1). See **Step 2** [in this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel).
- If you change the code, always re-test your function for language errors using menu **Debug** > **Compile**. If errors are shown, fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your function to something like this:

```
Function myaverage(x As Double, y As Double, z As Double) As Double
    myaverage = 0.4 * x + 0.5 * y + 0.1 * z
End Function
```

In Excel cell, use this:

```
= myaverage(A1, B1, C1)
```

Comment: okay. I found the error. If I type = myaverage(A1, B1, C1) instead of = myaverage(A1:C1) it's work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use range `A1:C1` as the input argument then UDF has to be written accordingly:

```
Public Function RangeAverage(rRef As Range) As Double
    With rRef
        RangeAverage = 0.4 * .Cells(1).Value2 + 0.5 * .Cells(2).Value2 + 0.1 * .Cells(3).Value2
        End With
End Function
```